# django orm group by taking value from order by

Tags: django

query_set = query_set.values('event','cat_type').annotate(cat_count=Count('id')).order_by("event__slug", "cat_type")

when I execute the sql query it returns, ... GROUP BY event_id,cat_type,event.slug,cat_type.

My question is 1.)why it considers the value written in ordey_by as Group by condition??
2.) Values('event') ----> returns event_id  not event obj  but How I can get event obj?

Answer (score 0):

```
.values
```

returns id not the object itslef.
To get the object you would have to use filter() or get()